Prove that the sub-boards cover at least half of the unit squares of the board
I found this problem in A path to combinatorics for undergraduates. This is problem 9.70.
Let $n$ be a positive integer. We are given an $n\times n$ chessboard. We call the intersections of $k$ adjacent rows and $l$ adjacent columns a $k\times l$ sub-board, and say that $k+l$ is the semiperimeter of the sub-board. Assume that some sub-boards with semiperimeters of n cover the main diagonal (the diagonal from the top left to the bottom right) of the board. Prove that the sub-boards cover at least half of the unit squares of the board.
Here is what I have tried
Let $S=\{a_1,a_2,..,a_m\}$ be a set of sub-boards with semiperimeters of $n$ such that S cover the main diagonal of the board.
Define, for any $i\in \{1,2,..,m\}$, the following sets $A_i=\{$unit squares of the board that $a_i$ covers$\}$ and let $b_i\times (n-b_i)$ be the dimension of $a_i$.
By the inclusion exclusion principle, we have
$$|\bigcup_{i=1}^m A_i|=\sum_{i=1}^m|A_i|-\sum_{1\le i\lt j\le m}|A_i\cap A_j|+...+(-1)^{(m+1)}|A_1\cap ...\cap A_m|$$
I don't know how to calculate the cardinalities of any set on the right hand side other than $|A_i|$, so I used Bonferonni inequality to obtain
$$|\bigcup_{i=1}^m A_i|\ge \sum_{i=1}^m|A_i|-\sum_{1\le i\lt j\le m}|A_i\cap A_j|=\sum_{i=1}^m(b_i)(n-b_i)-\sum_{1\le i\lt j\le m}|A_i\cap A_j|$$
Now I don't know how to show that right hand side is greater than $\frac{n^2}{2}$ and I'm not entirely sure if that's even true. I also feel that this approach may not work.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Hint: how many squares are covered in each column and row?

Let $S$ be the set of sub-boards with semiperimeters of n that cover the main diagonal. For any $j\in \{1,2,...,n\}$, let $d_j$ denote the unit square in the $j^{\text{th}}$ row and $j^{\text{th}}$ column. For each $d_j$, there exists a sub-board $s_j\in S$ of dimension $x_j\times y_j$ with $x_j+y_j=n$. So $x_j$ and $y_j$ unit squares are covered in the $j^{\text{th}}$ column and $j^{\text{th}}$ row respectively by $s_j$. Note that there could be other squares in the $j^{\text{th}}$ row and $j^{\text{th}}$ column that are covered by some other sub-boards. So we have $a_j+b_j\ge x_j+y_j=n$, where we define $a_j$ and $b_j$ to be the number of unit squares covered in the $j^{\text{th}}$ row and $j^{\text{th}}$ column respectively by the sub-boards $s_1, s_2,...,s_n$. Let $N$ be the total number of sub-boards covered by the sub-boards $s_1, s_2,...,s_n$. We have
$$N=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n (a_j+b_j)\geq \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n n=\frac{n^2}{2}$$
It follows that the sub-boards cover at least half of the unit squares of the board.
